# the css of the content in jquery dialog is getting overriden

Tags: jquery, css

okai I am using jquery dialog to show the content in the div

actually the html that i have to show in the dialog box , is coming from a database  column along with the css , and when I display that html in the dialog , the css of the parent page , starts overriding the css of the content in the dialog , since I already wrote the whole html and the css is coming from a database column  I cannot override anything , how can I make the dialog control stop inheriting any css from the parent page and only apply the formatting that's associated with the contained content

```
a simplistic example would be
<body I am the parent page  and my css is overriding the dialog div>
<div  id= dialog div>
<head>
hey I am the css from the db
</head>
<body>
hey I am the content from the db I am only suppose to format myself according to the css in my    head tag
</body>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Got some code for us there?

Comment: check I have edited my question with a prototypical example

Comment: Why use a _prototypical_ example?

Comment: because the css and content in the database is not In my control , the actually I am building an integration solution , the content is pulled into the  db column from another cms , its complicated !!!! please help me out

Comment: Is the csv overwriting like that? Creating multiple body tags, throwing in random div words outside of tags, etc? Because if it is, you're going to have to have a look at how it's being pulled in.

Comment: @user8189 have you fixed the problem?